# UBUNTU SPHINX FATAL: failed to open log file '/var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log': Permission denied, как исправить?

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx

у меня при вводе команды вылезает следующая ошибка.

```
/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart
Restarting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: key 'max_matches' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: key 'enable_star' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: key 'charset_type' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
FATAL: failed to open log file '/var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log': Permission denied
```

Я так понимаю, что у Сфинкса нет прав на запись.
Какие права нужно установить на папки

```
log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
query_log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
pid_file = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
binlog_path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/
path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/bitrix
```

чтобы сфинкс коррекно работал?
Я так понимаю, нужно создать пользователя сфинкс, верно?

Comment: В идеале да. И группу то же - чтоб было совсем правильно. Потом назначит на данные папки или файлы соответствующие права у пользователя Сфинкс

Comment: Я вижу, что в системе существует пользователь sphinxsearch
но процесс относится к моей учетной записи
ps auxwwww | grep sphinxsearch
Верно, ли, что я задала права 
    sudo chown -R my:my /var/log/sphinxsearch
    sudo chown -R my:my /var/run/sphinxsearch/
    sudo chown -R my:my /var/lib/sphinxsearch/
вместо
    sudo chown -R sphinxsearch:sphinxsearch /var/log/sphinxsearch/
    sudo chown -R sphinxsearch:sphinxsearch /var/run/sphinxsearch/
    sudo chown -R sphinxsearch:sphinxsearch /var/lib/sphinxsearch/